# url patterns like in two scoops of django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I like they way how pydanny and audrey write url patterns as they are readable:

```
url(
    regex='^expression/$',
    view=my_view,
    name='my_name'
),
```

But how do I write this when there are more arguments?

```
url(r'^account/login/$', login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
```

I tried:

```
url(
    regex='^account/login/$',
    view=login,
    template_name='login.html',
    name='login'
)
```

This doesn't work. How do I declare template_name this way?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap lines:

```
url(
    r'^account/login/$',
    login,
    {'template_name': 'login.html'},
    name='login'
)
```

or (if you prefer keyword argument style):

```
url(
    regex=r'^account/login/$',
    view=login,
    kwargs={'template_name': 'login.html'}, # NOT  template_name='login.html'
    name='login'
)
```

Comment: Yes, I like the keyword argument style. Your example gives an error: `keyword argument repeated`.

Comment: My bad. I typed `name=` instead of `view=`. Sorry about that.

Comment: By the way: is `'template_name':` still state of the art with django?

Comment: @wendy_winter, I don't know what do you mean. How about post another question?